# What is the purpose of a Pressurised hot water cylinder

Tags: hot-water

Does a pressurised hot water cylinder have to deal with just higher pressure mains cold water or does it also have to cope with the heating element being heated by a sealed high pressure central heating system.

To put it another way if I wanted to change to a sealed central heating system, but keep my hot water system as it is - open vented, could I keep my existing hot water cylinder or would i need to change it.

Comment: Your question make absolutely no sense, I have no idea what you are asking. What is a "hot water cylinder" you are speaking of?

Comment: Maybe lost in translation from English to American English. 'Hot water cylinder' is the tank that is used to store the hot water used for baths, hot water taps ectera. So Im asking if i keep Hot water as a gravity system, but change Ch heating to pressurized so it is now pressurized water going through the heat-exchanger in the cylinder do i need to replace the cylinder with a newer one, or would I only have to do that if I was changing the hot water system to a pressurized system.

Comment: I would recommend you change the title of your question to your actual question which appears to be something like " So Im asking if i keep Hot water as a gravity system, but change Ch heating to pressurized so it is now pressurized water going through the heat-exchanger in the cylinder do i need to replace the cylinder with a newer one, or would I only have to do that if I was changing the hot water system to a pressurized system." as opposed to beating around the bush.  I'd also recommend putting UK in the title since I don't believe we have cold water tanks in homes on this side of the pond

Comment: I dont think you can have question titles that long, but at least you understand the question even if you cannot give me an answer.

Comment: A couple of questions first please;  Are you talking about the hot water in your home that is used for bathing, washing of dishes and washing of clothes?  Or are you talking about the hot water that is circulated through out the house to provide space heating? Look closely at the system before you answer this question.  It make all the difference.

Comment: I think the question is quite clear, the hot water cylinder is for hot water fro bathing, washing etc. I'm talking about pressurising the hot water heated by the boiler and used for central heating, and fir indirectly heating the hot water in the hot water cylinder via the electric coil. The water that is actually in cylinder and comes out of the taps is not pressurised.